# Using Facebook presto-parser

Tags: java, facebook, parsing

I am trying to use [presto-parser](https://github.com/facebook/presto). What I need to know is how to analyze and extract the query body our of a created `Statement`:

```
SqlParser SQL_PARSER = new SqlParser();
Statement statement = SQL_PARSER.createStatement(query);
```

There doesn't seem any way to get that from the `Statement` getters/setters. I debugged the Statement object and I can see from the debug view the values I need to get.

See:

[image]

I need to get the select,from,where,groupBy,orderBy and limit values that were extracted out by the SqlParser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the sql string, you can get a `Query` (which extends Statement) by casting down the `Statement`. `Query.getQueryBody` returns a `QueryBody` which you can cast to a `QuerySpecification`(which extends `QueryBody`). From the `QuerySpecification`, you can now get what you're looking for. Here's a simple example:

```
public class PrestoParserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SqlParser parser = new SqlParser();
        String sql = "select * from xyz where x=y group by x order by y limit 10";
        Query query = (Query)parser.createStatement(sql);
        QuerySpecification body = (QuerySpecification)query.getQueryBody();
        Select select = body.getSelect();
        System.out.println("Columns = " + select.getSelectItems());
        System.out.println("From = " + body.getFrom().get());
        Optional<Expression> where = body.getWhere();
        System.out.println("Where = " + where.get());
        System.out.println("Group by = " + body.getGroupBy());
        System.out.println("Order by = " + body.getOrderBy());
        System.out.println("Limit = " + body.getLimit().get());

    }
}
```

Running this returns:

```
Columns = [*]
From = Table{xyz}
Where = ("x" = "y")
Group by = ["x"]
Order by = [SortItem{sortKey="y", ordering=ASCENDING, nullOrdering=UNDEFINED}]
Limit = 10
```

Comment: How about "UPDATE" statements, presto-parser does not seem to support that?

Comment: From a cursory glance through the codebase, it looks like its not supported. That's possible since the engine is not really meant for that, but I'd still be surprised if that were the case, simply from a completeness point of view.

Comment: `UPDATE` is not supported according to the [ANTLR definition file](https://github.com/facebook/presto/blob/master/presto-parser/src/main/antlr4/com/facebook/presto/sql/parser/SqlBase.g4).

Answer (score 2):

The problem has two parts

1. Visit entire AST (may be recursively)
2. Perform an operation on each node (In this case find the table nodes)

Following is an extensible solution :

```
class DepthFirstVisitor<R, C> extends AstVisitor<Stream<R>, C> {
    private final AstVisitor<R, C> visitor;

    public DepthFirstVisitor(AstVisitor<R, C> visitor) {
        this.visitor = visitor;
    }

    public static <R, C> DepthFirstVisitor<R, C> by(AstVisitor<R, C> visitor) {
        return new DepthFirstVisitor<>(visitor);
    }

    @Override
    public final Stream<R> visitNode(Node node, C context) {
        Stream<R> nodeResult = Stream.of(visitor.process(node, context));
        Stream<R> childrenResult = node.getChildren().stream()
                .flatMap(child -> process(child, context));

        return Stream.concat(nodeResult, childrenResult)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull);
    }
}

class Extractors {
    public static AstVisitor<Table, Object> extractTables() {
        return new AstVisitor<Table, Object>() {
            @Override
            protected Table visitTable(Table node, Object context) {
                return node;
            }
        };
    }
}

    
    // Thats it folks
DepthFirstVisitor<Table, ?> depthFirstVisitor = DepthFirstVisitor.by(Extractors.extractTables());

String sql = "select * from foo tablesample system (10) join bar tablesample bernoulli (30) on not(a.id > b.id)";
Statement statement = new SqlParser().createStatement(sql, new ParsingOptions());

List<Table> tables = statement.accept(depthFirstVisitor, null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(tables);
```

This can be done without making ugly type checkings.

Prints `[Table{foo}, Table{bar}]`

Answer (score 1):

While the given answers works, it requires lots of checking of types and casting at runtime which is super error prone. (Especially if you have a highly nested query with many joins and subexpressions)

Instead, Presto's query parser supplies a base `AstVisitor` abstract class that you can subclass and it will handle all the casting and dispatching for you.

https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-parser/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/sql/tree/AstVisitor.java

For example, to get a list of all tables used in a query (in scala, but the same applies to java):

```
class VisitSourceTables extends AstVisitor[List[String], List[String]]{

  override def visitTable(node: Table, context: List[String]): List[String] = {
    List[String](
      node.getName.toString
    )
  }

  override def visitJoin(node: Join, context: List[String]): List[String] = {
    process(node.getLeft, context) ++ process(node.getRight, context)
  }

  (one method per type of thing to visit)
  ...
}
```

And here is an example visitor that does not do anything useful but does traverse the query tree correctly. I found it really useful to figure out how to write my own:
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-parser/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/sql/tree/DefaultTraversalVisitor.java